# New to Blender. Why can't I interact with my rigging bones, Bones don't influence mesh and I can't to see where they are influencing the weight paint

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, weight-painting, rigify

Thank you in advance to anyone that helps me!!!

I've been working on this for a while now and about to start ripping my hair from my own rig. I think I have joined the rig correctly to the mesh with Parent- Weighted. But when I go into Pose mode none of my mesh moves with the bones. None of the Pose gridlines work or are interactive. Then when in weighted paint mode I can't see through the mesh to select bones to see where they are influencing.

I'm sure it's a simple mistake but I can't find any tutorials that actually explain this problem. [Picture 1: in Weighted paint mode][image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/